# Change uilabel height based on content in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I want to expand label's height based on the text inside. I use tableviewcontroller with static cells.

[image]

I have an `UILabel` in a tableview cell and I set top, bottom, right and left constraints of the label.

I tried these solutions:

```
self.eDesc.numberOfLines = 0
self.eDesc.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
self.eDesc.sizeToFit()
```

---

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But none of them worked.

Is there any other approach on this (maybe changing size by label frame)?

Comment: It is the only solution and 100% it is working, So let me know what is your output so that i can assist you according to it.

Comment: have you implemented heightForRowAt function and retuned UITableViewAutomaticDimension there, too?

Comment: @Kingalione I tried but now uilabel is completely disappeared. By the way i-It is a tableviewcontroller with static cells

Comment: I am editing the question with screenshots

Comment: @Krunal checking all of them again...

Comment: @Krunal I checked them and can confirm they exists :/

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz; You need to click on the label and set its content hugging to low and its resistance to high (or required depending on what other views are aligned with the label).

Comment: @Brandon will try that

Answer (score 9):

To set automatic dimension for row height & estimated row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout. I just tested following steps and code and works fine.

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension


    // Swift 4.1 and below
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    return UITableView.automaticDimension

    // Swift 4.1 and below
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

***Edit***: You must be missing top or bottom or height layout constraint for anyone UIElement in cell. Ensure all UIElements in cell, have valid top and bottom (and height, whereever required) constraints attached with it vertical (adjacent) UIElement.

**Note**: If you've more than one labels (UIElements) with dynamic length, which should be adjusted according to its content size: Adjust 'Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priority` for labels which you want to expand/compress with higher priority.

Here in this example I set low hugging and high compression resistance priority, that leads to set more priority/importance for contents of second (yellow) label.

[image]

Comment: I edited my question. You can see the results with this changes

Comment: This answer won't work at all when there is other content in the cell (Labels have the lowest priorities in AutoLayout).. You didn't adjust the UILabel's contentHuggingPriority and contentCompressionResistancePriority.. Hugging should be .defaultLow and resistance should be .defaultHigh to allow the label to resize based on its own contents which will force the cell to resize. Without this, if there's other content in any view that has a label, the label will take last priority and truncate or not show at all..

Comment: @Brandon - You are absolutely right but in this case it will show an error at design time with proper suggestion to set hugging priority. Another point is: OP had initially requested and asked for a single label, so I added a sample demo with single label. By the way thanks for your remark, you point should be noted and very essential. Hugging priority is required in case of multiple label. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have only 1 label to be adjusted. But I set low hugging and high compression resistance priority tho. And I added missing constraints. Now with heightForRowAt and UITableViewAutomaticDimension, it looks ok, however, UILabel still doesn't get adjusted.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Can you share a sample code/project with test information on git? So I can check, what's exact issue with this

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz A gentle suggestion: Remove all Elements from cell. Add only single dynamic label and test it. If you get successfully work with single label then one by one add other labels (and elements) into cell and ensure everytime (with addition of each UIElement) it works as expected.

Comment: Each cell has only 1 uilabel, check the screenshot. So that cell has the UILabel that I wanted to be adjusted has only 1 element. It should work actually but I can't understand. I am thinking that why apple made it so pain in the ars to adjust a label based on content.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Ohh, I got now.. You've used static cells with single elements in each cell right? Then this may not work. You can do it by using Custom cell easily.

Comment: @Krunal Yeah you got it! static cells with single elements. How can I do it that way?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Here is very simple and nice tutorial. I hope it will help you - https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/